# Replacing text fragments in places using php

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I need to replace strings in a text file using php. I have sample content:

> [prev title="sample1" cont="sample1a" res="sample1b" mw="1"][prev
>   title="sample2" cont="sample2a" res="sample2b" mw="2"][prev
>   title="sample3" cont="sample3a" res="sample3b" mw="3"]...

I need to move every fragment 'cont="sample" res="sample"' and insert between [prev title =], to get the result:

> [prev cont="sample1a" res="sample1b" title="sample1" mw="1"]...etc

I try to preg_replace something, but not very much

```
$getCont = file_get_contents($file);
$delText = trim(preg_replace('/prev.*?cont/', '/prev res.*? mw/', $getCont));
file_put_contents($file, $delText);
```

I already know that this is not the way. Can you help something?

Comment: Not clear from your expected output, do you want to reorder `title="sample1"` from every fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a positive lookbehind and 2 capturing groups and replace with group 2 and group 1:

`(?<=\[prev)( title="[^"]+")( cont="[^"]+" res="[^"]+")`

That will match

- `(?<=\[prev)` Positive lookbehing to assert that what is on the left is [prev
- `( title="[^"]+")` match title= including the double quotes and the content in group 1
- `( cont="[^"]+" res="[^"]+")` match cont= and res= including the double quotes and the content in group 2

Replace with switching group 1 and group 2.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ipk1vR/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/FuPpk)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option, using `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "[prev title=\"sample1\" cont=\"sample1a\" res=\"sample1b\" mw=\"1\"][prev title=\"sample2\" cont=\"sample2a\" res=\"sample2b\" mw=\"2\"][prev title=\"sample3\" cont=\"sample3a\" res=\"sample3b\" mw=\"3\"]";
echo $input;
$output = preg_replace('/(title=\"[^"]+\") (cont=\"[^"]+\") (res=\"[^"]+\")/', "$2 $3 $1", $input);
echo "\n" . $output;

[prev cont="sample1a" res="sample1b" title="sample1" mw="1"]
[prev cont="sample2a" res="sample2b" title="sample2" mw="2"]
[prev cont="sample3a" res="sample3b" title="sample3" mw="3"]
```

We match and capture the first three terms of bracketed entry, and then form a replacement with the order you want.

Comment: [Here](https://rextester.com/BPM41877) is a brief demo, not to be used or run in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by many ways e.g using **regex**, **reordering string** after exploding it and so on. A non-regex way of mine.

```
<?php
$str = '[prev title="sample1" cont="sample1a" res="sample1b" mw="1"][prev title="sample2" cont="sample2a" res="sample2b" mw="2"][prev title="sample3" cont="sample3a" res="sample3b" mw="3"]';
$arr = explode('][',$str);
$expected = '';
foreach($arr as $row){
    $res = explode(' ',trim($row,'[]'));
    $expected.= '['.$res[0].' '. $res[2].' '.$res[3].' '.$res[1].' '.$res[4].']';
}
echo $expected;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
[prev cont="sample1a" res="sample1b" title="sample1" mw="1"]
[prev cont="sample2a" res="sample2b" title="sample2" mw="2"]
[prev cont="sample3a" res="sample3b" title="sample3" mw="3"]
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/FE8Xq